# dropdownlist show resources culture asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-2

i have done it using html helper razor and work is properly.Here is my code snippet

```
    <a href="@Url.Action("data","Home", new { lang = "en"})">English</a> |
    <a href="@Url.Action("arabic","language", new { lang = "ar"})">Arabic</a>
    <a href="@Url.Action("  French ","language", new { lang = "fr"})">  French </a>
```

but i need converting into dropdownlist How it's??

Answer (score 1):

Create dropdown list with Razor:

```
@Html.DropDownList("language", new List<SelectListItem>
{
    new SelectListItem { Text = "English", Value="en"},
    new SelectListItem { Text = "Arabic", Value="ar"},
    new SelectListItem { Text = "French", Value="fr"}
})
```

and then use jQuery change() event on dropdown list to get value of selected language and redirect on desired url and query string param.

```
@section scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#language").change(function () {
            var url = "@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")?lang=" + $(this).val(); //Append language To URL
            window.location.replace(url);
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: #language where is came from

Comment: language is ID of dropdown list created with Razor. @Html.DropDownList("language" <---- this one here